# How to unit test a service which sets attribute to newly created object

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I want to write unit test for one of my service to verify certain fields get assigned.

```
public void createNewRecord(Dto dto) {
   Record record = new Record();
   record.setName(dto.getName());
   record.setDetail(dto.getDetail());
   repo.save(record);
}
```

I don't have a constructor for dto because a record has many attributes and some of them get assigned from other methods. My previous plan is: mock the record and verify `setName()` and `setDetail` methods are called once. But there is no way to inject mocked record into this service. Do I have to change my previous code? Any thought is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches:

**First:**

change method to this

```
public void createNewRecord(Record record, Dao dao)
```

**Second:**

Use PowerMockito to mock constructor

**Third:**

Use factory or com.google.inject.Provider for construct record (I prefer this)

**Forth:**

If record constructor is simple and setters for record also don't have some special logic then you can mock only repo and verify repo's argument.

Answer (score 0):

Mocks should be used for mocking a dependency of the tested object, not for mocking an inner object in the tested method.
Why don't you mock the repo instance and then you would verify with you mock api that repo.save() is called with the expected record ?
It seems to be a straight way to unit test your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) and its [@Captor](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#21) annotation to capture the arguments passed to the `repo` instance. You can `@Mock` the `Dto` object to create expectations for the `getName()` and `getDetail()` methods and assert that the results of invoking the `setName()` and `setDetail()` methods on the captured `Record` instance are the same values expected from the `Dto` object. For example:

```
@Mock
private Repo repo;

@Mock
private Dto dto;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Record> recordArgumentCaptor;

private Service service;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.service = new Service(repo);
}

@Test
public void shouldCreateNewRecord() {
    when(dto.getName()).thenReturn("NAME");
    when(dto.getDetail()).thenReturn("DETAIL");

    service.createNewRecord(dto);

    verify(repo).save(recordArgumentCaptor.capture());
    Record record = recordArgumentCaptor.getValue();

    assertThat(record.getName(), is(equalTo(dto.getName())));
    assertThat(record.getDetail(), is(equalTo(dto.getDetail())));
}
```